# Is it possible to export to PDF an HTMLTextArea using Ironpython on newer versions of Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

[Example Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyZ0y.png) Is it possible to export to PDF an HTMLTextArea visualization without being truncated on newer versions of Spotfire? If yes, it is possible to get a sample code?

Comment: can you please be more specific? maybe a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: @niko I just want to know if a HTMLtextArea in Spotfire can be exported to PDF in the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

I am using 10.2 right now and yes, it is possible to export an HTMLTextArea to PDF with IronPython.

here is the code I've used, mostly from the [TIBCOCommunity Spotfire Wiki](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-export-analysis-pdf-using-ironpython-tibco-spotfire):

```py
# Import namespaces
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import ApplicationThread
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Export import PdfExportSettings, ExportScope, PageOrientation, PaperSize, ExportScope

# Declaring the function which will run async
def g(app,fileName,pdfexpsettings):
   def f():      
      app.Document.Export(pdfexpsettings,fileName)
   return f

# Set the file name
fileName = "C:\\temp\\testfile.pdf"
pdfexpsettings = PdfExportSettings()
pdfexpsettings.Scope = ExportScope.ActiveVisualization
pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
pdfexpsettings.IncludePageTitles = False
pdfexpsettings.IncludeVisualizationTitles = False
pdfexpsettings.IncludeVisualizationDescriptions = False
pdfexpsettings.PaperSize = PaperSize.A4
pdfexpsettings.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape

# Executing the function on the application thread, and Save the document back to the Library
Application.GetService[ApplicationThread]().InvokeAsynchronously(g(Application, fileName,pdfexpsettings))

# Note:
# The function g is necessary because the script's scope is cleared after execution,
# and therefore Application (or anything else defined in this scope) will not be available
# when the code invokes on the application thread.
```

Comment: I have seen this and according to Tibco the PdfExportSettings is obsolete in 7.12 and forward and I know it is possible to export an HTML text area but I have an issue that it gets truncated on 7.11 according to other blogs this expected issue on 7.11, just wanted to check if that issue doesnt happen on 7.12 or newer versions

Comment: that is why I asked you for clarification or a screenshot; I wasn't sure what you meant by truncation... if you update your question with more information including what you have tried we can take a look at it and maybe come up with a better answer.

Comment: you should look at the page I linked. it also describes the new Reports API (I haven't played with it yet) which may be useful for you: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfirer-712-apis-exporting-and-rendering-visualizations

Comment: I am using 7.11 and I added an image to the issue I am having that is why I was asking if on 7.12 and forward this doesnt happen, it looks like it doesnt but not sure yet. If I can confirm this is not an issue on 7.12 maybe will do the upgrade

Comment: I can take a look when I get some time, but know that the latest LTS has been released as version 10.3, so regardless of the export feature it may be a good idea to upgrade anyway :)